# Typedef private struct prototype in source file

Tags: c++, pointers, implementation, pimpl-idiom

In my class I have the need to keep a pointer to a structure which is defined in a library I use to implement it. Since this library is only used within the implementation file I would like to avoid including it in the header directly. At the same time I want to avoid polluting the namespace. Thus I would like to do:

```
/* HEADER */
class Foo {
    private:
        struct ImplementationDetail;
        ImplementationDetail * p;
};
/* SOURCE */
#include <Library.h>
using Foo::ImplementationDetail = Library::SomeStruct;
```

But this doesn't work, and I'm currently falling back on PIMPL:

```
/* HEADER */
class Foo {
    private:
        struct ImplementationDetail;
        ImplementationDetail * p_;
};
/* SOURCE */
#include <Library.h>
struct ImplementationDetail {
    Library::SomeStruct * realp_; 
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the double dereference? Is the reason for my non-working first solution due to unknown pointer sizes?

Comment: _'Is the reason for my non-working first solution due to unknown pointer sizes?'_ 'non-working' is pretty vague, what's your concrete compilation/run time problems?

Comment: It depends on where I put the actual prototype. If it is private, it complains about that. If it is public, it complains about Foo not being a namespace.

Comment: You could look up the Private Implementation pattern (PIMPL).  I believe I read about it in big Design Patterns book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an incorrect declaration:

```
using Foo::ImplementationDetail = Library::SomeStruct;
```

`using` doesn't work this way.  In C++11 `using` cannot create an alias for a name in one namespace to a name in another namespace.  In C++03, all `using` does is bring some other namespace in to global visibility in the current translation unit.  It's not used to create aliases in C++03, as you seem to want to do here.

*pimpl* is the de-facto method for doing what you're trying to do, but in your header file instead of trying to use a `ImplementationDetail*`, I would use a simple `void*`.  Using a `void*` in this manner is guaranteed to be correct according to the Standard:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        void * pImpl;
```

Use `static_cast`<sup>2</sup> to go from a `void*` to your actual type:

```
void Foo::Bar()
{
  Library::SomeStruct* thingy = static_cast <Library::SomeStruct*> (pImpl);
  // ...
}
```

You can avoid using the `void*` in a conformant way by forward-declaring your library type:

```
namespace Library
{
  struct SomeStruct;
};

class Foo
{
private:
  Library::SomeStruct* pStruct;
};
```

And then no ugly cast is needed in the implementation.

---

<sup>2</sup> **Use `static_cast`** :  Or `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: Can't you `static_cast` to anything from void?

Comment: @MarkB:  Yes, you sure can.  I suppose that would be preferred normally -- I use `reinterpret_cast` party due to habit, partly due to my conception that it is a little more clear to other programmers.  Latter might be false.

Comment: In C++11, `using` is also used to declare type aliases. The only problem is that you can't put the declaration in a different scope.

Comment: I think the first paragraph should be rewritten, not only linked with a note.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Header
class Foo {
    private:
        struct ImplementationDetail;
        ImplementationDetail * p;
};

// Source
#include <Library.h>
struct Foo::ImplementationDetail :public Library::SomeStruct {
   // ....
};
```

and allocating/deallocating/dereferencing the pointer in this source file only should work just fine.

Comment: Anyway this would work if, say, Library contained a method like SomeStruct * getNewStruct() ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't take your first approach is that in the header you tell the compiler "I'm declaring a nested class within `Foo` and it's called `ImplementationDetail`". Then you proceed to say "wait wait, it's NOT a new class, it's an alias to this other thing entirely" and understandably the compiler gets confused.

Have you tried just forward declaring the library's implementation and using that instead of trying to create an alias?

Comment: I have thought about that. The problem is that the library I am using is in C, and thus I would create a global name for all to see, which nobody really cares about.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code you declared the nested type `ImplementationDetail` to be a `struct` which will be define inside `Foo`. Trying to alias it can't work because that would be a type defined elsewhere and, actually, you `private` structure isn't accessible from outside the class. Wrapping a pointer to another object inside seems unecessary: you could instead either embed the `Library::SomeStruct` by value or have your `ImplementationDetail` derive from `Library::SomeStruct`:

```
struct ImplementationDetail
    : Library::SomeStruct {
    using Library::SomeStruct::SomeStruct;
};
```

(the `using` declaration is just used to inherit all the constructors from `Library::SomeStruct`).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible without casting.

Basically there are two ways to do it:

1) Define p_ as `void*` and cast it in every function that uses it.

```
/* HEADER */
class Foo {
    private:
        void* p;
};

/* SOURCE */
#include <Library.h>

void Foo::AnyFunc()
{
    Library::SomeStruct* pImpl = reinterpret_cast<Library::SomeStruct*>(p);
    ...
}
```

2) Create a "shadowing"-class of your class (in the .cpp-file) with all members cloned and p_ defined as Library::SomeStruct. Then cast the `this`-pointer to this shadowing class. This is of course a quite insecure and dirty hack which I don't recommend...

```
/* HEADER */
class Foo {
    private:
        void* p;
};

/* SOURCE */
#include <Library.h>

class FooImpl
{
public:
    void AnyFunc() { p->DoSomething(); }

private:
    Library::SomeStruct* p;
}

void Foo::AnyFunc()
{
    FooImpl* pImpl = reinterpret_cast<FooImpl*>(this);
    pImpl->AnyFunc();
}
```

This exploits memory structure and is therefore quite fragile (all members need to be in the same order and when you add or remove members, you need to update ShadowFoo, too). I mentioned this just for completeness.

3) This brings us to yet another, but more simple way: create the implementation in the source file and initialize it in the constructor with the `void*`-pointer:

```
/* HEADER */
class Foo {
    private:
        void* p;
};

/* SOURCE */
#include <Library.h>

class FooImpl
{
public:
    FooImpl(void* pSomeStruct)
    {
        p = reinterpret_cast<Library::SomeStruct*>(pSomeStruct);
    }

    void AnyFunc() { p->DoSomething(); }

private:
    Library::SomeStruct* p;
}

void Foo::AnyFunc()
{
    FooImpl impl = FooImpl(p);
    impl.AnyFunc();
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote your answer (over the others, which are already correct) as soon you're showing working code samples.