# Having a typedef in the source file and a member variable in header

Tags: c++, header-files, pimpl-idiom

I have a class structure where I have some member variables declared like this:

```cc
/* HEADER */
#ifndef SRC_HEADER_H
#define SRC_HEADER_H

class Service {
 private:
  typedef boost::multi_index_container<...> Checkpoints;
  Checkpoints checkpoints_ GUARDED_BY(mutex_);
};

#endif
```

Then I have the source file with the implementation:

```cc
#include "src/header.h"

/* some functions which use `checkpoints_` */
```

Is there a way I could move the typedef from the header file to the source file and keep the member `checkpoints_` there in the header file only? I am trying to make the header file lighter since this `multi_index_container` might become a heavy container with repercussions on compile time.

Comment: Have you tried `class Checkpoints;` in the header?

Comment: @Sebastian: You can’t forward declare a typedef like that, even if it happens to be exactly a class type.

Comment: Oh thx. What is the size of _checkpoints? You tagged pimpl, change member variable to pointer or wrapper class, which just contains a pointer?

Comment: Decided to move forward with the pimpl approach. Luckily, I found something I needed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620243/typedef-private-struct-prototype-in-source-file

Answer (score 1):

You can't forward declare a typedef in a header file, however, the pImpl idiom can be taken as inspiration to implement the thing in the question.

I found the relevant information here:
[Typedef private struct prototype in source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620243/typedef-private-struct-prototype-in-source-file)